# How to `git add` a file named `foo/.git/bar`?

Tags: git

No matter how I try, I can't get `git` to track my file named `foo/.git/bar`.

### What I've tried

```
git add foo                     # no result
git add foo/.git                # no result
git add foo/.git/bar            # no result
git add --force foo/.git/bar    # no result
cd foo && git add .git          # no result
```

I understand that usually you wouldn't want to track such a file. I think that my use-case justifies it though.

### My use case

I have a file named `foo/.git/hooks/pre-push` in my git repository.
I will be using [GNU stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) to install this `pre-push` file into a git repository somewhere else on my disk. To be clear, the folder `foo` is *not* a git repository; it is just a folder named `foo` that happens to contain a folder named `.git` and a file `.git/hooks/pre-push`. I want to track it.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: In the usual way of working with Git, a directory named `.git` *is* the repository, located in a working directory that contains files checked out of the repository for editing. Why do you have a directory named `.git` that *isn't* the repository, and where is the repository if not in `.git`?

Comment: Yes @the_previ, I was trying put git hooks and git config files (`.git/hooks/...` and `.git/config`) under version control. The plan was to use GNU stow to install the hooks and the config file.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Seriously, you can't.  Git forbids you from having a file named `.git`, in any upper or lower case mix, or any file with any component (part between slashes) whose name is `.git`, in any upper or lower case mix.

Name the file something else.

Comment: At first I read the first sentence as "God forbids you from..."
Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't as it was said. Just to extend the previous answer - if you want to do this for hooks what you can do is to have hooks simply in `<repo>/hooks` and script or `Makefile` target to setup developer environment that will put these in proper place. If you document that in `README.md` or `CONTRIBUTING.md` and tell people to run script as first thing it works pretty well and will also work for things beyond `git`.

Also note it's not good idea to trust hooks on developer machine, even if developer forgets to install hooks that e.g. check code, add signature, etc. Remote CI or VCS server should catch these bad pull requests and reject them.